# TypoScript: conditional wrap if more than one item

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x, fluid-styled-content

hmm... my TypoScript skills seem to have become a bit rusty.

```
 lib.feld < styles.content.get
 lib.feld.select.orderBy = rand()
 lib.feld.select.select.where = colPos=11
 lib.feld.wrap = <div class="wrapper">|</div>
```

I would like to add the wrapper div only if `styles.content.get` returns more than one item for said `colPos`.

I've tried the following two variants:

```
lib.feld.wrap.if {
    isGreaterThan.numRows < styles.content.get
    isGreaterThan.numRows.select.where = colPos=11
    value = 1
}
```

and

```
lib.feld.wrap.if {
    isGreaterThan.numRows.table = tt_content
    isGreaterThan.numRows.select < styles.content.get.select
    isGreaterThan.numRows.select.where = colPos=11
    value = 1
}
```

also with an additional `stdWrap` before numRows.
Everything returns false, even when there should be multiple results.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from typoscript definition I would guess:

```
temp.feld < styles.content.get
temp.feld.select.where = colPos=11
temp.feld.select.orderBy = rand()
temp.feld.select.pidInList = 123

lib.feld < temp.feld
lib.feld.wrap = <div>|</div>
lib.feld.wrap.if {
    isGreaterThan.stdWrap.numRows < temp.feld
    value = 1
}
```

for inspecting/debuggung the value of `numRows` you might use this:

```
lib.numRows = TEXT
lib.numRows.numRows < temp.feld
lib.numRows.wrap = numRows=[|]
```

which you can use in fluid

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.numRows')}
```

or in typoscript itself for output

```
page.3 < lib.numRows
```

Comment: It produces an error, but I could add `isGreaterThan.stdWrap.numRows.table = tt_content` and the error is gone. Still, I haven't got it to work yet. I also forgot a line in the question. Will edit it right now

Comment: you are right: I forgot the table. I changed my example to copy the complete CONTENT object though only table and select are neccessary

Comment: if you are unsure about a rendered typoscript value try to print it. I will add a section to my answer.

Comment: Wonderful, I've been asking that myself all the time, how I could debug TS better.

Comment: you also can use the [admin-panel](https://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/installation/adminpanel-admpanel.html).

Comment: Which option(s)? Track content rendering?

Comment: Actually it wasn't typos only: pidInList was missing. It was provided by a constant that was received in TS later on, after the `if` condition had been executed

Comment: how could it be? all typoscript constants are resolved (recursive) before rendering of typoscript setup is started.

Comment: It's not actually the constant that is changed, it's the TS that receives the constant later on (the constant is something `storagePidSection1 = 123`, and then in TS later on `pidInList = {$storagePidSection1}` etc